# change the executable JAR file permissions accordingly:

Tags: linux, sudo

I've created a user using  `sudo useradd -m peris`, then I want to change an executable JAR file permissions, but I got an error:

```
$ sudo chmod 500 menu-prices-update-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[sudo] password for peris: 
peris is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
```

Comment: You will need to set the user up with the command "visudo"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit the `/etc/sudoers` and add the user **peris** into it. Either open the file with your favorite edit, for example `vim`:

```
$ sudo vim /etc/sudoers
```

and add the user there under `root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL` with the same syntax:

```
peris    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

Or just edit it via the command `visudo`. **NOTE**: You must do this with root privileges, i.e. `sudo`.